# Show the while remaining time with jprogressbar?

Tags: java, while-loop, jprogressbar

I have several big DB file on a folder that I handled them with a while in JAVA, how can I show the remaining time as percent with JProgressbar ?

```
public int countTrueAmr(String text, String under,String value, String search) {
        int sLen = under.length();
        int count = 0;
        int index = text.indexOf(under + value, 0);
        int nextIndex = text.indexOf(under, index + sLen);
        while (index > 0 && nextIndex > 0) {
            count += countString(text.substring(index, nextIndex), search);

            index = text.indexOf(under + value, index + sLen);
            nextIndex = text.indexOf(under, index + sLen);
            if (nextIndex < 0)
                nextIndex = text.length();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extend `SwingWorker`.
2. Override `doInBackground()`.  Put the loop inside.  Call the method `publish(...)` once in a while.
3. Override `process(...)`.  Call `JProgressBar`'s `setValue(i)`.

Comment: Please see the tutorial : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please give me an example?

The `SwingWorker` [`setProgress()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#setProgress%28int%29) method should be used so that the GUI is "notified asynchronously on the *event dispatch thread*." There's an example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata) and in the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).